# Formatar Consulta Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Estou querendo ajustar minha consulta em Python para que eu consiga gerar corretamente um gráfico em Chart.js.

Tenho o seguinte código para consulta e geração do arquivo json

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    weatherData = WeatherData.objects.filter(row_id=1, sensor_id=1)
    date = [obj.date for obj in weatherData]
    value = [float(obj.value) for obj in weatherData]

    context = {
        'date': json.dumps(date, default=json_serial),
        'value': json.dumps(value),
    }
    return Response(context)
```

Porém esse código está gerando um arquivo no seguinte formato

```
{'date': '["2019-09-25T17:57:07+00:00", "2019-09-25T17:57:55+00:00", "2019-09-26T12:19:31.694958+00:00", "2019-09-30T01:43:21+00:00", "2019-09-30T17:06:58+00:00", "2019-09-30T17:11:39+00:00", "2019-09-30T17:12:03+00:00", "2019-09-30T17:13:51+00:00", "2019-09-30T17:16:05+00:00"]',  'value': '[10.0, 10.0, 4.5, 70.4,
70.4, 70.4, 70.4, 70.4, 70.4]'}
```

O que estou precisando é que seja gerado um arquivo no formato

```
{ date: "2019-09-30T17:16:05+00:00", value: 70.4 }, { date: "2019-09-30T17:16:05+00:00", value: 70.4 }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado para não estar gerando dessa maneira meus arquivo JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem apenas um objeto iterável, `weatherData`, e está criando duas listas separadas, uma para a data

```
date = [obj.date for obj in weatherData]
```

e outra para os valores:

```
value = [float(obj.value) for obj in weatherData]
```

Se você precisa apenas de uma lista que cada item possua dua data e valor, basta fazer:

```
context = [{'date': obj.date, 'value': float(obj.value)} for obj in weatherData]
```

Assim estará iterando apenas uma vez sobre seu objeto original e criando uma lista de dicionários contendo cada um a chave `date` e a `value`.

E retornar na resposta `Response(context)`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Problema solucionado.